# MemoryMarshal.Cast Only value types without pointers or references are supported

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

Hello I am working on a project where I have to cast a byte array from a UDP package into a data struct. This struct contains arrays with a fixed size. However, when casting the byte array with the following line:

```
var telemetry = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, F122_Stucts.PacketSessionData>(bytes);
```

I get the following exception:

> Only value types without pointers or references are supported

It goes wrong with the MarshalZone and WeatherForecastSample arrays in the struct. My struct looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0, Size = 632)]
public struct PacketSessionData
{
    public PacketHeader m_header;         // Header

    public byte m_weather;                // Weather - 0 = clear, 1 = light cloud, 2 = overcast
                                          // 3 = light rain, 4 = heavy rain, 5 = storm
    public sbyte m_trackTemperature;        // Track temp. in degrees celsius
    public sbyte m_airTemperature;          // Air temp. in degrees celsius
    public byte m_totalLaps;              // Total number of laps in this race
    public UInt16 m_trackLength;               // Track length in metres
    public byte m_sessionType;            // 0 = unknown, 1 = P1, 2 = P2, 3 = P3, 4 = Short P
                                          // 5 = Q1, 6 = Q2, 7 = Q3, 8 = Short Q, 9 = OSQ
                                          // 10 = R, 11 = R2, 12 = R3, 13 = Time Trial
    public sbyte m_trackId;                 // -1 for unknown, see appendix
    public byte m_formula;                    // Formula, 0 = F1 Modern, 1 = F1 Classic, 2 = F2,
                                              // 3 = F1 Generic, 4 = Beta, 5 = Supercars
                                              // 6 = Esports, 7 = F2 2021
    public UInt16 m_sessionTimeLeft;       // Time left in session in seconds
    public UInt16 m_sessionDuration;       // Session duration in seconds
    public byte m_pitSpeedLimit;          // Pit speed limit in kilometres per hour
    public byte m_gamePaused;                // Whether the game is paused – network game only
    public byte m_isSpectating;           // Whether the player is spectating
    public byte m_spectatorCarIndex;      // Index of the car being spectated
    public byte m_sliProNativeSupport;    // SLI Pro support, 0 = inactive, 1 = active
    public byte m_numMarshalZones;            // Number of marshal zones to follow
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 21)]
    public MarshalZone[] m_marshalZones;             // List of marshal zones – max 21
    public byte m_safetyCarStatus;           // 0 = no safety car, 1 = full
                                             // 2 = virtual, 3 = formation lap
    public byte m_networkGame;               // 0 = offline, 1 = online
    public byte m_numWeatherForecastSamples; // Number of weather samples to follow
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 56)]
    public WeatherForecastSample[] m_weatherForecastSamples;   // Array of weather forecast samples

    public byte m_forecastAccuracy;          // 0 = Perfect, 1 = Approximate
    public byte m_aiDifficulty;              // AI Difficulty rating – 0-110
    public UInt32 m_seasonLinkIdentifier;      // Identifier for season - persists across saves
    public UInt32 m_weekendLinkIdentifier;     // Identifier for weekend - persists across saves
    public UInt32 m_sessionLinkIdentifier;     // Identifier for session - persists across saves
    public byte m_pitStopWindowIdealLap;     // Ideal lap to pit on for current strategy (player)
    public byte m_pitStopWindowLatestLap;    // Latest lap to pit on for current strategy (player)
    public byte m_pitStopRejoinPosition;     // Predicted position to rejoin at (player)
    public byte m_steeringAssist;            // 0 = off, 1 = on
    public byte m_brakingAssist;             // 0 = off, 1 = low, 2 = medium, 3 = high
    public byte m_gearboxAssist;             // 1 = manual, 2 = manual & suggested gear, 3 = auto
    public byte m_pitAssist;                 // 0 = off, 1 = on
    public byte m_pitReleaseAssist;          // 0 = off, 1 = on
    public byte m_ERSAssist;                 // 0 = off, 1 = on
    public byte m_DRSAssist;                 // 0 = off, 1 = on
    public byte m_dynamicRacingLine;         // 0 = off, 1 = corners only, 2 = full
    public byte m_dynamicRacingLineType;     // 0 = 2D, 1 = 3D
    public byte m_gameMode;                  // Game mode id - see appendix
    public byte m_ruleSet;                   // Ruleset - see appendix
    public UInt32 m_timeOfDay;                 // Local time of day - minutes since midnight
    public byte m_sessionLength;             // 0 = None, 2 = Very Short, 3 = Short, 4 = Medium, 5 = Medium Long, 6 = Long, 7 = Full
};
```

The struct arrays look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0, Size = 5)]
public struct MarshalZone
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float m_zoneStart;   // Fraction (0..1) of way through the lap the marshal zone starts
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public sbyte m_zoneFlag;    // -1 = invalid/unknown, 0 = none, 1 = green, 2 = blue, 3 = yellow, 4 = red
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 0, Size = 8)]
public struct WeatherForecastSample
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte m_sessionType;              // 0 = unknown, 1 = P1, 2 = P2, 3 = P3, 4 = Short P, 5 = Q1
                                            // 6 = Q2, 7 = Q3, 8 = Short Q, 9 = OSQ, 10 = R, 11 = R2
                                            // 12 = R3, 13 = Time Trial
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte m_timeOffset;               // Time in minutes the forecast is for
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte m_weather;                  // Weather - 0 = clear, 1 = light cloud, 2 = overcast
                                            // 3 = light rain, 4 = heavy rain, 5 = storm
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public sbyte m_trackTemperature;         // Track temp. in degrees Celsius
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public sbyte m_trackTemperatureChange;   // Track temp. change – 0 = up, 1 = down, 2 = no change
    [FieldOffset(5)]
    public sbyte m_airTemperature;           // Air temp. in degrees celsius
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public sbyte m_airTemperatureChange;     // Air temp. change – 0 = up, 1 = down, 2 = no change
    [FieldOffset(7)]
    public byte m_rainPercentage;           // Rain percentage (0-100)
};
```

Is there any way I can convert this byte array into this structure?

Comment: `Memory` doesn't do marshalling, it expects plain unmanaged byte arrays. Instead you can use `Marshal.Copy` or `Marshal.PtrToStructure`